# wysihtml5 alignment is not coming properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not very good CSS. I've been trying this for past 2 hours but I'm not able to align my wysihtml5 elements properly. by default wysihtml5 component comes in "li" tag and and I'm using "li" tag for showing bullets so it is affecting wysihtml5 component also.
I've attached snapshot for clarification.

[image]

components like Heading, Bold, italic, underline and other elements are coming in new line. I want all of them to be in same line.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add css. 
Add this line.

```
li{list-style-type: none;display: inline-block;}
```

Explanation:

- list-style-type: none will remove black dots in front of li. you can use square, circle... if you want...
- display:inline-block will make li in one line...
- you can add class in front of li (e.g. : .class li) to make it more specific...

Comment: code is working fine but this affects the normal "li" item that i'm using. so is it possible if i can apply this css only to specific "li" elements like which lies under class wysihtml5-toolbar?
i tried wysihtml5-toolbar > li{list-style-type: none;display: inline-block;} , but it is not working

Comment: it worked. I missed .(dot) before the class name. Thanks